# position MediaController inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-view, android-mediaplayer

I've noticed a problem concerning the position of a `MediaController` for a `VideoView` inside a `Fragment`. 
Here's a screenshot of how it looks on Nexus 7 running Android 4.3:
[image: Screenshot of app with MediaController on 4.3]

And here's a screenshot of the app on Nexus 7 running Android 4.2.2:
[image]

As you can see, the position of the MediaController is in the middle of my Activity on API 17 or lower (tested on another tablet with 4.1.2 as well). I've noticed that the size of the MediaController is correct.

My Fragment is shown in a FrameLayout whose width is defined by it's weight (0.6 here), so not by a specific dpi value.

I've checked the source code of MediaController on [Grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/widget/MediaController.java#MediaController) and compared the one of 4.3 with the code of 4.2.2 and there are some small changes with the LayoutParams, but I can't find a way to make this work.

I initialize my VideoView and MediaController in the onActivityCreated() of my Fragment

```
mMediaController = new MediaController(getActivity());
mMediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(mMediaController);
```

Does somebody know how I can position it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we will need custom MediaController to alter it's weird behaviour in android prior 4.3

```
class CustomMediaController extends MediaController
{

    public CustomMediaController(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomMediaController(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomMediaController(Context context, boolean useFastForward) {
        super(context, useFastForward);
    }

    @Override
    public void show(int timeout) {
        super.show(timeout);
        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion < 18) //android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2
        {
            try {
                Field field1 = MediaController.class.getDeclaredField("mAnchor");
                field1.setAccessible(true);
                View mAnchor = (View)field1.get(controller);

                Field field2 = MediaController.class.getDeclaredField("mDecor");
                field2.setAccessible(true);
                View mDecor = (View)field2.get(controller);

                Field field3 = MediaController.class.getDeclaredField("mDecorLayoutParams");
                field3.setAccessible(true);
                WindowManager.LayoutParams mDecorLayoutParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams)field3.get(controller);

                Field field4 = MediaController.class.getDeclaredField("mWindowManager");
                field4.setAccessible(true);
                WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager)field4.get(controller);

                int [] anchorPos = new int[2];
                mAnchor.getLocationOnScreen(anchorPos);

                // we need to know the size of the controller so we can properly position it
                // within its space
                mDecor.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mAnchor.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
                                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mAnchor.getHeight(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));

                WindowManager.LayoutParams p = mDecorLayoutParams;
                p.width = mAnchor.getWidth();
                p.x = anchorPos[0] + (mAnchor.getWidth() - p.width) / 2;
                p.y = anchorPos[1] + mAnchor.getHeight() - mDecor.getMeasuredHeight();
                mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mDecor, mDecorLayoutParams);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then just replace MediaController in variable declaration with CustomMediaController and everything will do. The reason is android code prior to 4.3 was bugged. We're using reflection to correct position in **show()** method.

Tested with android 4.0.

Comment: What is that "controller" object ?

Comment: What is the controller ?